# Reference block is invalid during Transfer

Tags: nodeos, cleos

I Tried the transfer of 1 eos from my account to other, to day just for some test transfer, i am using cleos to transfer but when i did it throwed the exception

> Error 3040007: Invalid Reference Block Ensure that the reference block
>   exist in the blockchain! Error Details: Transaction's reference block
>   did not match. Is this transaction from a different fork?

can anyone help me with this, i am running 5 nodes of EOS currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you are generating your transaction, it is filling it with a reference block in the transaction JSON. The problem is that the reference block should be a short time in the past, and in your case that isn't true. Are you generating the transaction on your local testnet, and then trying to sign and push it to a different chain? That would be a typical reason to get this error

Comment: sorted out thanks :)

Comment: What was the problem exactly?

Comment: i found that my nodes were not running, because of chain_db_size problem, i change in configini from 1024 to 65536, and ran all the nodes then tried and it started working, i used --hard-replay to restart all the node, after increasing the storage size and chain_db_size in config

Comment: @PhillipHamnett-EOS42 I encountered this error while creating a account on jungle test net.

Comment: @Nirdesh If this question and answer don't help then make a new question showing the steps you have taken and the error message and I'll answer it there